# Check a line value in python from a file

Tags: python

So I have this .txt file that has over 100 lines and a value on each one.
How would I read the value from a specific line and use it in an if?
Let's say I want to read the line 34 and see if the line has the value 0 or 1 in it. I don't really know how to explain but i was thinking about something like this. would I be able to assign "print(lines[34])" an integer and then compare the integer with 0 or 1? please keep in mind that i have no experience with python.

```
f = open("NT.txt",'r')
lines = f.readlines()
if print(lines[34]) == 1:
    print("something")
```

Comment: With the exception of an error your `if` line, that code should work.  Your `if` line should actually be `if lines[34] == 1:` instead of the way it currently is.  You're on the right track.

Comment: @DougR. close at least ... would still never enter his if ...

Comment: Gack! Totally forgot that it needed to be converted to an int!  That's the problem with a quick answer.

Comment: ...and of course, by the time I posted the correction as an answer, you'd already posted it yourself.

Comment: :P im ninja like that sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if lines[34].strip() == "1":
```

since files are always text ... might answer your question?

(note that since lists start with 0 `lines[34]` is the 35th line)

of coarse someone may have told you to try

```
if int(lines[34])==1:
```

and you heard `print` instead of `int`

Answer (score 1):

As @JoranBeasley pointed out to my solution in the comment up there, anything read in from a text file is read in as...text (duh!).  It would need to be converted to an int, so the proper `if` statement should be:

```
if int(lines[34].strip()) == 1:
    # Do something here.
```

Additionally, most folks would probably open the text file using a `with` statement, so that it closes automagically when you're done using it:

```
with open('NT.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
if int(lines[34].strip()) == 1:
    # Do something here.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
f=open('NT.txt', 'r')
lines=f.readlines()

if int(lines[34])==1:
    print('something')
```